# Angular firestore creating saving data under ID field of type map

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create field from angular component to add to firestore collection. Fields are UserId and Details. Details is in a form in html but userid comes from parent component , and suppose to be saved in the collection. When form is submitted, fields are created but userID is under 'ID' of type map. How do I save only as userID. It is getting the 'ID' from the main component where declared Opendialog
service

```
 addDetails( id: string,details: Users) {
  this.db.collection('detailscollection')
  .add(details)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('Successfully');
  })   
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error ' ,error);
  });    
}
```

Main Component

```
 openDialog() {
        const MatDialogRef = this.dialog.open(DetailsDialogComponent, {
          height: '220px',
          width: '250px',
          data: {
            userID: this.id,
          }
        } 
          );
```

DetailsDialogComponent.ts

```
  ngOnInit(){     
     
      this.userForm = new FormGroup({
        'details' : new FormControl(),        
      })      
    }
  onSubmit() {

    let details:Clients = {
      id: this.data,
      notes: this.userForm.value.user,
    } 
     this.userService.addDetails(this.id, details);
   
  }
```